# Menustrip sub item control in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, interface

I have a menustrip that consists of two items Project and Customer. Based on the ID of the user, each item will have different sub-items. However, the problem that I am facing is how to connect each sub-item with a specific form. Throughout my search, I did the following:

```
Dim userid = Textbox1.text
if userid = "1001" then
                Dim p1 As New ToolStripMenuItem
                p1 = Form1.ProjectToolStripMenuItem
                p1.DropDownItems.Add("Add Project")
                AddHandler p1.DropDownItemClicked, AddressOf add_project_click
                Dim p2 As ToolStripMenuItem
                p2 = Form1.ProjectToolStripMenuItem
                p2.DropDownItems.Add("Modify Project")
else
                    Dim p2 As ToolStripMenuItem
                    p2 = Form1.ProjectToolStripMenuItem
                    p2.DropDownItems.Add("Modify Project")
end if
    Private Sub add_project_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        AddProjectForm.Show()

    End Sub
```

The problem now with `AddHandler p1.DropDownItemClicked, AddressOf add_project_click` because when I click on Project item and I click either Add Project or Modify Project, both will show the form of Add Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your add_project_click's method's definition so that e is a ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs instead of the EventArgs type.  Then you can use e.SelectedItem.Text to determine which item was clicked.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim userid = "1001"

    Dim p1 As New ToolStripMenuItem

    p1.Text = "Menu Item"

    If userid = "1001" Then

        p1.DropDownItems.Add("Add Project")

    End If

    p1.DropDownItems.Add("Modify Project")

    MyMenuStrip.Items.Add(p1)

    AddHandler p1.DropDownItemClicked, AddressOf add_project_click

End Sub


Private Sub add_project_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs)

    If e.ClickedItem.Text = "Add Project" Then

        'AddProjectForm.Show()

    Else

        'ModifyProjectForm.Show()

    End If

End Sub
```